# VEINS - BSM MESSAGES

Tags: veins

in veins simulator, i want to implement a v2x secanrio where vehicles send BSM messages to RSU and RSU send TIM messages to vehicles ( as in SAE J2735 STANDARD)
in which file in Veins can i change WSM messages to BSM messages ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to model TIM messages (or, really, any type of message) in Veins, you just need to know

1. how long such a message is in real life (measured in bits) and
2. what information such a message represents in your simulation model (in terms of what data fields are stored in the C++ class).

Both are treated independently in Veins (i.e., you can store a gigabit of data in the C++ class and still have a message represent only a few bits of user data -- or, vice versa, you can store only a simple boolean in the C++ class and the message represent a kilobyte of data).

You can examine the Veins tutorial simulation that ships with Veins 5.0-alpha2 to get some inspiration for how to do this: it uses a [custom message type that stores data specific to the application](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11pMessage.msg#L34) and [sets the length (measured in bits) of this message](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/DemoBaseApplLayer.cc#L176) to accurately model how long such a message would be in real life. On the application layer, the needed information is then [stored into](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L100) and [read from](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5a1/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L57) this custom message type.

Comment: thank you for your help . I will try to solve my problem